# How to create a bar plot with the same column from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

Here is how the graph currently looks, but I want it to have just 3 bars, s1, s2, and s9 for the x value and the microns on the y, but for some reason there are 5 separate colors for the bar and the x-axis is just an extension of the y axis.

[image: Graph]

Here is the code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the future, **[no screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of text. All posts should be **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({f'{col}': d.TDT for col, d in zip(['s1', 's2', 's9'], [s1, s2, s9])})` to create the dataframe from multiple dataframes. `sns.barplot(data=df, estimator=sum, ci=None)` : The correct and simplest way is to specify the `estimator`.

Comment: Create a single dataframe from the beginning with an identifying column is probably better: `df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(d).assign(source=f's{i}') for i, d in enumerate([data1, data2, data3])), ignore_index=True)` and plot with `ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='source', y='TDT', estimator=sum, ci=None)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking for just one bar for each of the columns s1, s2, s9 and the sum of all the columns in those to be the height of each of these bars, you should be using `barplot()` instead. Get the sum of each column using `sum()` and then plot it. Below code shows this for some random data. The sum() will get the total for each column and doing a reset_index() will add the column names as a column index. You can try print `box_data.sum().reset_index()` to understand how the sum data looks like.

**Code**

```
data = {'s1': np.random.randint(20,160, size=(100)),
        's2':np.random.randint(16,80, size=(100)),
        's9':np.random.randint(60,170, size=(100))}
box_data=pd.DataFrame(data)

sns.barplot(data = box_data.sum().reset_index(), y=0, x= 'index')
```

**Plot**
[image]